# Python: Transform a unicode variable into a string variable

Tags: python, unicode, casting, web-crawler, unicode-string

I used a web crawler to get some data. I stored the data in a variable `price`. The type of `price` is:

```
<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
```

The type of each element of `price` is:

```
<type 'unicode'>
```

Basically the `price` contains some white space and line feeds followed by: `$520`. I want to eliminate all the extra symbols and recover only the number `520`. I already did a naive solution:

```
def reducePrice(price):
    key=0
    string=""
        for i in price:
            if (key==1):
                string=string+i
            if (i== '$'):
                key=1
    key=0
    return string
```

But I want to implement a more elegant solution, transforming the type of `price` into `str` and then using `str` methods to manipulate it. I already searched a lot in the web and other posts in the forum. The best I could get was that using:

```
p = "".join(price)
```

I can generate a big unicode variable. If you can give me a hint I would be grateful (I'm using python 2.7 in Ubuntu).

**edit** I add my spider just in case you need it:

```
def spider(max_pages):
        page = 1
        while page <= max_pages:
            url = "http://www.lider.cl/walmart/catalog/product/productDetails.jsp?cId=CF_Nivel2_000021&productId=PROD_5913&skuId=5913&pId=CF_Nivel1_000004&navAction=jump&navCount=12"
            source_code = requests.get(url)
            plain_text = source_code.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
            title = ""
            price = ""
            for link in soup.findAll('span', {'itemprop': 'name'}):
                title = link.string
            for link in soup.find('em', {'class': 'oferLowPrice fixPriceOferUp  '}):
                price = link.string

            print(title + '='+ str(reducePrice(price)))
            page += 1

spider(1)
```

**edit 2** Thanks to Martin and mASOUD I could generate the solution using  `str` methods:

```
def reducePrice(price):
   return int((("".join(("".join(price)).split())).replace("$","")).encode())
```

This method return an `int`. This was not my original question but it was the next step in my project. I added it because we can't cast unicode into `int` but using encode() to generate a `str` first, we can.

Comment: Did you try looking for bs4 to string? You are close.

Comment: I tried `str(price)` and then `price.strip()` but it didn't work.

Comment: can you post your bs4 code? Did you try str(price[0])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a RegEx to extract the price from your Unicode string:

```
import re

def reducePrice(price):
    match = re.search(r'\d+', u'  $500  ')
    price = match.group()  # returns u"500"
    price = str(price) # convert "500" in unicode to single-byte characters.
    return price
```

Even though this function converts Unicode to a "regular" string as you asked, is there any reason you want this? Unicode strings can be worked with the same way as a regular string. That is `u"500"` is almost the same as `"500"`

Comment: it looks quite elegant, yet I wonder if I can transform a variable of type unicode into string.

Comment: Added some extra text at the end - is there any reason you want to convert to a string? Unicode is also a "string".

Comment: I know. But I can't use string's methods in a unicode "string" and I want to know if it is posible to do the conversion just to learn for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: Which method can't you use?

Comment: `price.strip()` for example.

Comment: `strip` definitely works on a unicode string. Simple example: `u"         500    ".strip()` which returns `u"500"`

Comment: I review my code and I think you are right. I was committing a stupid mistake. Let me check again.

Comment: If you really just need to convert a unicode string to a regular "python2" string you can encode() it. like: u'hi'.encode() which will give you 'hi'.

Comment: I didn't use RE but you guys helped me to solve this. I can't vote up you but I will accpet this answer mostly for the comments. Thanks!